# Datasnap query client side

Tags: delphi-xe, datasnap

I don't understand how to use parameters, to find a proper example of using parameters is a bit difficult. I did manage to use clientdataset filters it does the job, but I am sure it can be done with sql as well. datasnap does not allow such queries , I have read on my research that i must use parameters. I just don't get it. I need a proper example where a server/client is setup using datasnap and  can query from the client similar to the sql: `SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE person = 20`

this will give me all people with the age of 20 in a dbgrid. like I said I have manage to do this with filters but the filters is not a 100% correct one or two odd records makes it appearance.

your assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How you connected clientdataset to server?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to work with ClientDataset and parameters. Try this one.

Server Side:

1. Put an TSqlQuery on ServerClass and enter Sql Statement in it form:

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE person = :person`

   set paramenter properties to the correcto paramenter type and data type.
2. put a TDatasetProvider and connect to TSQLQuery
3. Run Server.

Client Side:

1. Put a TDSProviderConnection and connect to the server and assign ServerClass
2. Connect TClientDataset to TDSProviderConnection and select TDatasetProvider  name.
3. Right TClientDataset and select FetchParams

Now you can assign any value to this parameter an let the Datasnap framework do the rest.

Check these sources for more information:

- Article: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41189
- Demo : http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28188

Answer (score 0):

**Set SQL command:**

```
qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE age = :age';
```

Define the parameter type to Integer

**Set parameter value:**

```
qry.ParamByName('age').AsInteger := 20;
```

**Open the query:**

```
qry.Open;
```